# Graphviz creates two arrows between subplots

Tags: graphviz

I want to create a graphviz graph which contains two subgraphs containing nodes which are linked to other nodes in the other graph.
Some nodes need to be aligned horizontally to each other.

I've found out about the `newrank=true` command and I'm using it to achieve my described goal.
For some reason I've found that really weird behaviour: 
If I create two nodes in one cluster and an arrow from one to the other and then another arrow pointing towards a third node in another cluster, graphviz will display two arrows.

```
digraph g{
    newrank=true;

    subgraph cluster_d{
        A -> B
    }
    subgraph cluster_v{
        C
    }
    {rank=same; A, B, C }
    B -> C    
}
```

[image: result of above code]

I know, that I could simply use `rankdir=LR` and remove the `rank=same`, but in a larger graph with more nodes and subgraphs I seem to run into this problem sooner or later anyway.
I just created the artificial example above, to narrow the problem down.

Here is the code in use:
https://hackmd.io/s/B1NXAiTk7#

Why does Graphviz create two arrows between the subgraphs and how can I prevent this?

Related to: [Why is graphviz drawing two arrows, and using a weird order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442917/why-is-graphviz-drawing-two-arrows-and-using-a-weird-order)
But there was no satisfying answer and I think I narrowed the problem down.